# Trying to consolidate and/or CONCAT ItemNumber with NumberOfDaysBetweenOrders

Tags: sql, sql-server

Right now I currently have the `NumberOfDaysBetweenPurchases` per `ItemNumber` by `AccountNumber`.  I'm trying to CONCATENATE the `ItemNumber|AVERAGENumberOfDaysBetweenPurchases`

I have two issues. 1, I cannot find a way to get the average for all of the Days between Orders. 2, I cannot get this to display without Ordering/Grouping by Account Number or Purchase Date. So it always displays by breaking out millions of rows for each time the product was ordered by a customer.

Here is what I'm using to get the `NumberOfDaysBetweenPurchases`:

```
datediff(day, lag(OrderDate,1) over (partition by AccountNumber 
order by OrderDate), OrderDate) as [NumOfDaysBetweenOrdersByAccountNum]
```

**How do I consolidate the `ItemNumbers` so that they only show up once along with the Average Number of Days Between Orders by Account Number? I'd like it to show up like this:**

```
ItemNumber | AvgNumberOfDaysBetweenOrdersByAccountNumber
12345         6
452234        45
5235          3
```

Here's an example of what my current info looks like (millions of rows):

```
ItemNumber | NumberDays(...)  | OrderDate | AccountNumber
123           0                   ----        101010
123           1                   ----        101010
123           4                   ----        101010
123           7                   ----        101010
123           8                   ----        101010
```

Comment: Can you show us the sample of the data you have?

Comment: Just edit the question and add the information there.

Comment: Made an edit in the question. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: What is the NumberDays(...) column storing?

Comment: `NumberOfDaysBetweenOrdersByAccountNumber` from `datediff(day, lag(OrderDate,1) over (partition by AccountNumber order by OrderDate), OrderDate) as [NumOfDaysBetweenOrdersByAccountNum]`  in my SELECT statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can understand of your question, try this.

`WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ItemNumber, ItemNumber, AccountNumber,
        datediff(day, lag(OrderDate,1) over (partition by AccountNumber order by OrderDate), OrderDate) as [NumOfDaysBetweenOrdersByAccountNum] 
)
SELECT
    ItemNumber
    , AVG(NumberOfDaysBetweenOrdersByAccountNum)
FROM
    cte
GROUP BY
    ItemNumber`

Comment: This is working fantastically, but I'm getting a lot of 1 values. The only thing I need now to get useful data is to be able to filter results based on if the AccountNumber purchased the ItemNumber more than X number of times. I need to say `WHERE` the ItemNumber and AccountNumber appear together more than X number of times. Sorry for the noob questions